# Find out the animation duration of the current animation block

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

Inside a UIView animation block, is there a way to get the current animation's duration?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    // float duration = ?
}];
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, wouldn't the animation duration be 1.0?

Comment: yes, but I'm using a component inside the block that needs to know the duration, and I don't want to pass the duration as a variable

Comment: Good question +1 sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: I don't think it is possible without a variable... Is there a particular reason for not using it?

Answer (score 5):

If you are targeting `iOS 9.0` or later, then you are looking for a class property of `UIView`, called `inheritedAnimationDuration`.

Usage:

```
let currentAnimationDuration = UIView.inheritedAnimationDuration
```

From **Apple docs**:

> **Summary**
>
> Returns the inherited duration of the current animation.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This method only returns a non-zero value if called within a `UIView` animation block.

Comment: Thanks it saves a lot of my time

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: use CALayer -actionForKey:, not -animationForKey:

@Dimitri Bouniol 's answer didn't work for me when called from an an affected setter inside an animation block.  The reason, from my understanding, is that UIView's animation system sets up state before starting the actual animation (and calls setters before starting the actual animation).  What worked for me though was calling the similar -actionForKey: method on the layer.  The action returned did have the proper duration set, and can be used as it is in his answer.

```
CAAnimation *animation = (CAAnimation *)[self.layer actionForKey@"position"]; // or property of interest

[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:animation.duration];
[CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:animation.timingFunction];

// CALayer animation here

[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Doesn't work in iOS 11. `actionForKey:` returns a `_UIViewAdditiveAnimationAction` that conforms to the `CAAction` protocol but is not a `CAAnimation`. So the `timingFunction` property doesn't exist. @Dimitri Bouniol's answer works for me.

Answer (score 1):

`[CATransaction animationDuration]` is what you're looking for

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work, the UIView animation block apparently doesn't work directly with CATransaction.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using blocks, why not just capture a variable with it?

```
CGFloat duration = 1.0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{ 
    CGFloat theDuration = duration; 
}];
```

Comment: Agree. We already passing duration then why should we find another way for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current animation easily enough. For instance, setting up a `CATransaction`:

```
CAAnimation *animation = [self.layer animationForKey:self.layer.animationKeys.firstObject];
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:animation.duration];
[CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:animation.timingFunction];

// CALayer animation here

[CATransaction commit];
```